# Multiple aliases for multiple joins?

Tags: mysql

I have this query on two tables, resulting in (image attached)

```
    SELECT vcc.name, vcc.quantity, vcc.custom_message, vfd.value
FROM vxu_4_wpsc_cart_contents AS vcc
INNER JOIN vxu_4_wpsc_submited_form_data AS vfd ON vcc.purchaseid = vfd.log_id
WHERE vfd.form_id
IN ( 2, 9 )
```

I'd like to a) remove repeat data and b) have 2nd 'value' entry in the same row, so I get 'name' 'quantity' custom_message' 'value 1(full name)' 'value 2(email)' in one row.
I think that involves multi table aliases and multi joins, but don't have the brains to figure it out! I've tried - honest!

[the two tables plus result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpN1n.jpg)

Comment: You should add the tables into the question.  Relying on an external web site to explain the question is a bad idea.  At the very least, you should show the results the query now produces and the results that you want.

Comment: Not sure whether I understood the question but you can join multiple times the same table under different aliases: `FROM table1 AS t1 JOIN table2 AS t2 ON... JOIN table2 AS t3 ON ...`.

Comment: Not sure how best to add the tables to the question, hence the attached image of the tables ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply join the second table another time, use exact `form_id` match instead of `IN` and move it to `ON` clause.

```
SELECT vcc.name, vcc.quantity, vcc.custom_message, vfd1.value AS full_name, vfd2.value as email
FROM vxu_4_wpsc_cart_contents AS vcc
INNER JOIN vxu_4_wpsc_submited_form_data AS vfd1 ON vcc.purchaseid = vfd1.log_id AND vfd1.form_id = 2
INNER JOIN vxu_4_wpsc_submited_form_data AS vfd2 ON vcc.purchaseid = vfd2.log_id AND vfd2.form_id = 9
```

Additionally, if it's possible that full name or email are not specified (there's no row with form_id = 2 or form_id = 9), but you still need that data in result, consider a left join instead.

Comment: Thank you Timekiller. Works like a dream, first time. Genius.